# While using readlines and .split() function, would it be easier to iterate through with for-loop?

Tags: python, file, for-loop, split

I've created a while loop to iterate through, read the data.txt file, calculate the perimeter/area/vertices, and the root will print out the answers.

I'm stuck here:

```py
from Polygon import Polygon
from Rectangle import Rectangle

in_file = open('data.txt', 'r')

line = in_file.readlines()

while line:
    type_, num_of_sides = line.split( ) ###ERROR 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

    sides = [map(float, in_file.readline().split()) for _ in range(int(num_of_sides))]
    print(line)

    if type_ == 'P':
        poly_object = Polygon(sides)

    elif type_ == 'R':
        poly_object = Rectangle(sides)

    print('The vertices are {}'.format(poly_object.vertices))
    print('The perimeter is {}'.format(poly_object.perimeter()))
    print('The area is {}'.format(poly_object.area()))
    print()

    line = in_file.readline()

in_file.close()
```

Should I create a `for` loop that loops through since `readlines` is a list of strings and I want the split to read through each line? Or is it just the way that I'm choosing to format, so that's why I'm getting an error?

Comment: You need to change `line = in_file.readlines()` to `line = in_file.readline()` (singular).

Comment: Instead of `in_file.readlines()`, you should simply use `in_file.read()`, then later, `type_, num_of_sides = line.splitlines()`

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue is use of `readlines`, not `readline` in `line = in_file.readlines()`. This will populate `line` with a list of all lines from the file, rather than a single line. This will lead to two issues with your program where the wrong type of data will propagate through the loop:

1. Calling `while line`, in this instance, after reading a non-empty file will cause the loop to be executed, because a non-empty list evaluates to true.
2. You call `split` on `line`. On the first iteration of the loop, `line` contains a list of strings (where each string was a line in the file). Lists to do not have a `split` method – only the individual strings do. This call fails.
3. If the call to `split` had not failed and the loop had been allowed to run through once, the subsequent call to `line = in_file.readline()` would not return the next line in the file, as all lines have been read by the earlier call to `readlines` and the cursor not reset in the intervening period from EOF. The loop will terminate.

If you did not have the final call in step 3, the loop would instead run forever without termination, as the value of `line` would never be updated to be a non-empty list.

---

A minimal change is to adjust the initial call which assigns a value to the `line` variable to `readline()` rather than `readlines()` to ensure only a single line is read from the file. The logic in the code should then work.

---

You may find the following implementation logic easier to implement and reason about:

- collect the machinery for reading from `in_file` together into a single block *before* the loop, using a context manager to automatically close the file on leaving the block
- producing a list of lines, which a simple `for` loop is sufficient to iterate over

```py
# This context manager will automatically ensure `in_file` is closed
# on leaving the `with` block.
with open('data.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    lines = in_file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    # Do something with each line; in particular, you can call
    # split() on line without issue here.
    #
    # You do not require any further calls to in_file.readline()
    # in this block.
```